# How to comment/uncomment in bulk in wikidata's SPARQL gui by shortcut?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

Wikidata provides a tool for query building.

https://query.wikidata.org/

But I cannot find any shortcut in the editor to comment/uncomment in bulk (that is, comment/uncomment multiple lines at the same time).

Comment: What do you mean by comment? Do you mean [qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Qualifiers)? Anyway, Wikidata does not allow SPARQL update queries from this public endpoint. Probably you could use some command-line tool for batch editing. [An example](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Creating_a_bot#Example_8:_Add_a_qualifier).

Comment: Or do you just want to comment/uncomment lines in your query?

Comment: @StanislavKralin : I mean just comment/uncomment in my query

Comment: for comment one line: `#` Do you need comment several lines?

Comment: @Alexan : Yep.Also updated the question

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can comment only by line.

Comment: This feature is pending code review now: https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/c/436174/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of June 2018, the SPARQL query editor at https://query.wikidata.org/ lets you select several lines and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to bulk (un)comment.  *(This feature was not available when the original question and answer were written.)*

The SPARQL language does not have a "multi-line comment" indicator, only "the rest of this line is a comment" hash ("`#`") indicator.

<strike>Some text editors will let you add the same prefix to multiple lines with one command; this requires that you edit your query outside of most SPARQL endpoint webforms.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

This is now [fixed](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/c/436174/).   You can select a few lines and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to bulk comment/uncomment them.